# How to convert utc timestamp to local browser time

Tags: reactjs, date

I get the UTC timestamp("2018-06-20 08:01:04") from the server and i would like to convert it to local browser time. how could i do it with reactjs. Is there some date object method that can do this. thanks.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, native and with libraries. That's not part of the React library. Check out momentjs for starters. But this is really a matter of opinion. https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score -1):

Use [date-fns library](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns)

```
import parse from 'date-fns/parse'

const timestamp = "2018-06-20 08:01:04"
const parsed = parse(timestamp)
console.log(parsed) // your date
```